# How to undo DROP TABLE statement without backup in SQL?

Tags: sql, undo

How to undo DROP TABLE statement without backup in SQL?

Comment: Ooops.You cant.Use backups.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, DB2 etc.) you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Did you already commit the drop? If not, you can rollback it in some DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle then you can use flashback drop. For more details check this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm

```
SQL> drop table mytab;

Table dropped.

SQL> select original_name from dba_recyclebin;

Original Name
-------------------------------- 
MYTAB 

SQL> flashback table MYTAB to before drop;

Flashback complete.

SQL> select * from mytab;

ID 
---------- 
2 
2
```